# Creating a function identical to str.title() function in Python

Tags: python, function, refactoring, title

My exercise is to write a function that works identically as the `str.title()` function. here's my poor solution so far

```
def my_title(s):
  list = []

  for char in s:        
      if char.isalpha():
         char = char.lower()
      list.append(char)

  for n in range(0,len(list)):
      if list[n].isalpha():
          list[n]=list[n].upper()
          break

  return ''.join(list)
```

Can you refactor this to 1 loop?

Comment: Before refactoring, you should have a function that actually works, which this doesn't.

Comment: or improved in any way you think....not necessarily to 1 loop

Comment: Why is the first loop necessary at all? Just call `.lower()` on the string. For non-alpha chars it will just return the original char.

Comment: I agree with Daniel -- please show us code that actually works, and then we'll help to improve it. Otherwise we'll be doing your homework for you.

Comment: when I run this in IDLE...print(my_title("1   33333ddedeEEEEE34343")) I  get "1   33333Ddedeeeeee34343" as outcome, same as doing "1   33333ddedeEEEEE34343".title()

Comment: It looks like you're converting your string to a list to allow item assignment (i.e. `list[n] = 'a'`). You can create a list of characters, all in lower-case, by calling `list(s.lower())` (that is, as long as you don't have a variable that is also called `list`).

Comment: Thanks Hannele! With the function you mentioned I can now remove the first loop :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another regex solution, just for fun:

```
re.sub(r'\b\w', lambda m: m.group(0).upper(), s.lower())
```

This matches any "word character" at the beginning of a word and capitalizes each of them.

Answer (score 2):

Can it get simpler than this?

```
def my_title(s):
    l = ''
    for n in range(0,len(s)):
        l += s[n].lower() if n and s[n-1].isalpha() else s[n].upper()
    return l
```

Comment: fp...help me understand your code....should I type the line under the for loop as I see it on screen? what is l used for?

Comment: I used `l` instead of list. Add `return l`. It isn't good to use a reserved word for a var. It isn't a list now.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = list("1 33333ddedeEEEEE34343")
caps_flag = True
for i,c in enumerate(s):
    if c.isalpha():
        if caps_flag:
            caps_flag = False
            s[i] = c.upper()
        else:
            s[i] = c.lower()

print ''.join(s)
```

**Better version based on FatalError's comment**

```
s = list("1 33333ddedeEEEEE34343".lower())
for i,c in enumerate(s):
    if c.isalpha():
        s[i] = c.upper()
        break


print ''.join(s)
```

Comment: Hi John, I got this error when running your code: TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment.....but I may be mistaken, have you tested it?

Comment: @Kokas, ... hmmm strange. Are you using python 3 or 3.3? I am using python 2.7 and my test worked.

Comment: I am using Python 3.3.0...but I cannot get it to run on 2.7.3 either...I must be doing something wrong then...

Comment: Actually mine breaks for "1 33333ddedeEEEEE34343eeeEE", you should probably use @fp's solution.